# Error while starting the Oracle Weblogic Server 11g

Tags: weblogic11g

When I'm starting the weblogic server, I'm getting the below error.

```
<Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application 'myapp_weblogic
_10' due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: .
weblogic.application.ModuleException:
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.session.IBMSessionListener
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

As the error shows that ClassNotFoundException occurs for "com.ibm.websphere.servlet.session.IBMSessionListener".

But I'm not finding how to resolve this error.
Also in Weblogic Server Console, it's showing that application state is "FAILED" in deployement section.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Your application **myapp_weblogic** contains a web application, in which the web.xml defines a session listener using class `com.ibm.websphere.servlet.session.IBMSessionListener`. Judging by the name, this session listener class is provided by IBM Websphere. Thus it is not available in Weblogic. Remove this session listener from the web.xml should fix the server startup issue. But if this session listener is important to your application, you need to see how to migrate it onto WLS server.